# Regarding "New page" event in Active reports 9?

Tags: c#, activereports, grapecity

Am working on a section report , The problem am facing is i have group say **"Country"** i bind **"country Id"** as Data Field to this group. In detail section i have 3 text Boxes one for **"State"**, other for its **"Capital"** and other text box for consistent spacing for Next state.

**"         "-- Concistent space of 0.25f;**
**"Telangana"**
**"Hyderabad"**

**"         "-- Concistent space of 0.25f;**
**"Andhra pradesh"**
**"Amaravathi"**

Now, when the detail section is auto filled by data fields(state and capital). The detail section is set to group keep together property to **"true"**, when there is not enough space to fit in page it goes to next page that's working fine till now but when it starts freshly in new page i dont need any consistent spacing.

problem is with detail section is executing and after execution then its checking whether it can fit or not and then its going to pagefooter and then in new page before going to page header event its printing the detail section, which it has already executed in previous page.

So is this a bug or there is no event in the cycle of active reports9 to find ,that its (Detail) going to New page when it dont have space in that page.

Need some assistance. 
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

basically you want the spacing only if the detail has not moved the group to a new one.

This might work, but i have not tried it.

in groupHeader format set the space control width to 0.25 and set a local variable to currentPagenumber.   in groupHeader beforePrint check if the currentPagenumber is = to the local variable, i.e. you are still on the same page, if not change the width of the space control width to 0.

Comment: i tried this before prior asking the question. Here, what's happening is that till the local variable and current page number changes i.e.. when its entering new page the logic what i have wrote is applying for next items on that New page, for the current items they are printing with space as the detail section was executed in previous page itself. Need some assistance quickly Thanks.

Comment: can you share the code that you tried.   if the code is in beforePrint it should execute for items that have moved.  Can you add debug code to shoe when is the GH beforePrint event is called (after NewPage) and what the value of your local variable is at the time.

Comment: @ GrapeCity Team , suppose say Detail consists of data comes dynamically from data source. If that data is large so that it takes max of 3 pages to fit. The Detail section is executed and after that Detail_Before Print Executed . Then Detail checking that data cant be fit in to this page, so it prints in next page(by this time detail execution completed). In next page ,In page header event am checking by that time data is Printed in that page.